# How to set up a variable in static const char?

Tags: c++, libcurl

I'm following this code:

https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/docs/examples/smtp-tls.c

Using it in a C++ environment, I would like to add variables to the email message itself. For example:

```
static const char *payload_text[] = {
  "Date: Mon, 29 Nov 2010 21:54:29 +1100\r\n",
  "To: " TO "\r\n",
  "From: " FROM " (Example User)\r\n",
  "Cc: " CC " (Another example User)\r\n",
  "Message-ID: <dcd7cb36-11db-487a-9f3a-e652a9458efd@"
  "rfcpedant.example.org>\r\n",
  "Subject: SMTP TLS example message\r\n",
  "\r\n", /* empty line to divide headers from body, see RFC5322 */
  "This message is being sent because ", reason, "\r\n",
  NULL
};
```

"Reason" could be a variety of things ranging from a reminder, to a indication that a user has broken the rules, etc. I can't put a string in there, so I was wondering how I would be able to add variables to the message.

EDIT: I would also like to be able to allow the user to have input on a variable as well. This is my current message:

```
const char *user = {
    "John Doe"
};

const char *reason = {
    " this is a test."
};

static const char *payload_text[] = {
  "Date: Mon, 29 Nov 2010 21:54:29 +1100\r\n",
  "To: " TO "\r\n",
  "From: " FROM " (Example User)\r\n",
  "Cc: " CC " (Another example User)\r\n",
  "Message-ID: <dcd7cb36-11db-487a-9f3a-e652a9458efd@"
  "rfcpedant.example.org>\r\n",
  "Subject: SMTP TLS example message\r\n",
  "\r\n", /* empty line to divide headers from body, see RFC5322 */
  "Hi, ", user, " you have received this message because " , reason "\r\n",
  NULL
};
```

I'm just trying to figure out how the user and program could determine these variables.

Comment: Make `reason` a pointer that points to whatever text payload you want?

Comment: @SidS Well if `reason` is a `const char*` then when the OP goes to use payload they can do `std::string payload = convert_everything_you_want_to_add_to _a_string; reason = payload.c_str(); use_payload_text`.  Then when they want to use it again they either change `reason` to point to something else or have it still pointing to some persistent data.

Comment: The code in the link is an example, all very constant. You would be building your own payload yourself anyway. I'd be reaching for `std::stringstream` for versatility.

Comment: @NathanOliver, It still wouldn't work because the array is `static`.  It can only be set up once.

Comment: @SidS Doh, forgot about that.  You'd have to have it point to a big enough buffer and just fill that buffer.  Not as elegant that way :(

Comment: @Jazael, Why are you using `static` ?

Comment: Because that's in the example. I'm rather new to this and still figuring out how it works and what substitutions I could make (if any) to make this more feasible to what I'm going for. Right now, I'm just trying to edit the example to use some different features, such as printing different variables in the email itself.